# Simplest Way to Schedule Multiple Webjobs from DevOps

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-webjobs

I have an app service in Azure running the front end from my MVC5 app, and another app service for web jobs. The app has several endpoints (GET Actions) which do some processing, send some emails or other simple task. Previously when we were hosted on a VPS, we used the Windows Task Scheduler to call each URL on a custom schedule. In Azure, the way we're currently doing this is with a Powershell script which uses CURL to fetch the URL and trigger the processing.

It seems messy though - as each powershell script has to be uploaded individually, and can't be viewed or changed after uploading. I've found various guides on deploying a .NET Core console app, but from what I can tell each job would need it's own project, deployed with it's own pipeline.

Is there a nicer way of doing this, are Webjobs even the right tool for this job, given the seemingly simple task we're performing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your use case, you can use **Azure Function App Timer Trigger** to accomplish it.

*A timer trigger lets you run a function on a schedule.*

The following example shows a C# function that is executed each time the minutes have a value divisible by five (eg if the function starts at `18:57:00`, the next performance will be at `19:00:00`). The `TimerInfo` object is passed into the function.

```
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Timer is running late!");
    }
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

The attribute's constructor takes a `CRON` expression or a `TimeSpan`. You can use `TimeSpan` only if the function app is running on an App Service plan. `TimeSpan` is not supported for `Consumption or Elastic Premium Functions`.

[**CRON (NCRONTAB expressions)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions)

Comment: Is it possible to run multiple jobs with this approach though? Or is the scheduler in Azure looking for the `Run` entrypoint to know what to execute (a single job)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the scheduler looks for `Run` entry point. But, you can add multiple such `Run` entry points in one Function App.